# How to export 3ds and animation together?

Tags: animation

I am using an engine(Blitz3D) that exclusively only supports .3ds and .x file formats.
I have found a  demo of a walking character and the code made Blitz3D extract the animation from the .3ds file somehow.
When I export the .3ds file, I have no animation. I tried opening the exported .3ds file with animation in Blender, but it also had no animation. 
I made a simple walking animation that is just rotating. 
It has no skeleton because the character is just a collection of cubes and I needed a simple animation(I tried doing a skeleton, it just turned out very horrible, weight painting didn't help at all).
So I just made it without the skeleton and it looked good.
Can someone please tell me how to export animation together with .3ds if that's possible?

Comment: As far as I know 3ds file format doesn't support animation data, or at least blender doesn't read or write it

Comment: Is it some old implementation that isn't valid any more? Because even when I imported it to Blender, the character from the demo was distorted and glitched extremely. Should I install an old version of Blender to make it work?

Comment: @John Doe I fixed the animation export in blender version 4.0, you can check the alpha version here: [Blender daily builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/)